# disable auto link in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

If I write some URL in source code comments like:

```
/**
 * Here is an inline link [test](http://www.test.com).
 * More information:
 * <a href="http://www.test.com">test</a>
 */
```

I enabled `GENERATE_XML` in Doxygen. This is what it generates:

```
<para>Here is an inline link [test](<ulink url="http://www.test.com">http://www.test.com</ulink>).
More information:
<ulink url="http://www.test.com">test</ulink> </para>
```

After converting the tags, I can create a Markdown content like:

```
Here is an inline link [test](<a href="http://www.test.com">http://www.test.com</a>).
More information:
<a href="http://www.test.com">test</a>
```

Note that the Markdown link `[test](<a href="http://www.test.com">http://www.test.com</a>)` is polluted, which will break the link after I feed this into another Markdown processor. I need this as I want to write some markdown in comments, and extract it to some structured data formats for other tools to processing the markdown. I have disabled `MARKDOWN_SUPPORT` in Doxygen.

I have tried disable `AUTOLINK_SUPPORT` in doxyfile, but it can only disable internal type link to class/method/...

Comment: Can you specify the doxygen version you are using, the differences between the standard ```Doxyfile``` (doxygen configuration file) and include a, small, code snippet that shows the problem.

Comment: How about: ```[test](%http://www.test.com)``` ?

Comment: @albert Thank you! It worked. In our scenario, it's ideal to fix this issue in tooling to avoid changing existing source code. But it's also acceptable if there is a good reason to do so. Is there any document on this from Doxygen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for the mentioned problem, auto linking a web address, is to use `[test](%http://www.test.com)`. By means of the `%` sign the (automatic) linking is suppressed.

In the documentation, paragraph "Step 3: Documenting the sources":

> Links are created for words corresponding to documented classes (unless the word is preceded by a %; then the word will not be linked and the % sign is removed).

Note: in the above quote the wording is only for classes but it does work on other places as well. The same "problem" occurs in other places:

- Description of AUTOLINK_SUPPORT
- FAQ Doxygen automatically generates a link to the class MyClass somewhere
  in the running text. How do I prevent that at a certain place?
- Paragraph Links to classes
- Paragraph "\%"